# Force empty block element to have a width

Tags: html, css

I'm using inplace edit plugin that needs a block element in order to know which element is editable when clicked. I've done it that way in ASP .NET:

```
<div class="editable-alias" style="background-color: red; width: 100%;"><%# ViewModel.Alias %></div>
```

However if `ViewModel.Alias` is empty, then surrounding `<div>` is empty, and as a result its width is 0, and it's impossible to click it. Is there a way to style that div (or perhaps span with inline-block) to have width even if it do not have content?

Comment: have you tried with `&nbsp;` inside your div when ViewModel.Alias is empty?

Comment: I think you want it to have a height as well, not just width...

Comment: I tried &nbsp; , but then the editable plugin inserts it into input textbox. So it's not a solution in this case

Comment: which editable plugin are you using?

Comment: I use this one: http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html . Thanks for jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
<div class="editable-alias" style="display:block; background-color: red; width: 100%;"><%# ViewModel.Alias %>&nbsp;</div>
```

You may also specify a `min-height` along with this